# How can I change encoding to UTF-8 for linux redirection..?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Currently I use vm in GCP.
I want to get stackdriver logs to text file(my log includes Korean(unicode).)

When I try to read using gcloud command, I can read my log (Korean also readable..)
But when I try write to file using redirect command (>),  all Korean characters converted to '???'

my command is here:

```
gcloud beta logging read --project=[my project] '[filters]' > log
```

How can I read korean character via file?

Thanks :)

Comment: From internal research, I noticed that there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/119117189). However there is no ETA

Comment: same problem here, any thoughts please anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed by setting PYTHONIOENCODING to utf-8.

You can do this by adding `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 gcloud ...`

Comment: This solves the problem indeed, should be accepted as the correct answer.. Thank you!